# any chrome plugin to protect saved passwords

Tags: passwords, google-chrome-extensions

Is there any plugin in chrome to protect my saved passwords from prying eyes?
I have a laptop and some times it is difficult to avoid giving laptop to people.

**EDIT**

I use Linux not windows and sharing laptop can not be avoided.Firefox has a master password sort of feature is there some thing similar for Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Chrome password cache is stored encrypted.

On Linux by using gnome-keyring or the kde kwallet (see [the announcement](http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-dev/browse_thread/thread/814d112acb8944c2?pli=1%20))

On Windows with your Windows logon credentials (similar to Internet Explorer's password cache).

On MacOsX by using the Keychain Access (see [the help](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95606))

So, on disk the passwords are stored safely, and you can simply:

> Avoid to give people access to an unlocked user session.

If someone wants to borrow your laptop, hit:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (on Linux)
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (on Windows)

and let them fast-user-switch to a guest profile (on certain Gnome systems or MacOsX) or their own profile (If they have one).

Instead of a built-in guest account, obviously you can also simply create a standard user account on your machine, named e.g. `Forrest Gump`. If anyone wants to use the computer, they can use the Forrest Gump account. "My account is **my** account, and i'm not telling anyone my password."

Comment: "The Chrome password cache is encrypted with your Windows logon credentials" - any reference on that?

Comment: I’d also be interested in the encryption method—though I don’t feel like browsing through the source. (You can view the encrypted passwords in `Login Data.logins.password_value`.)

Comment: @grawity (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chromepass.html)  "In order to use this feature, you must know the last logged-on password used for this profile, because the passwords are encrypted with the SHA hash of the log-on password, and without that hash, the passwords cannot be decrypted. "

Comment: @Ian: While I use Nirsoft utilities often, I'd prefer a more detailed explanation on the encryption used; for example, just how does Chrome know my logon password? I would guess it doesn't and just calls CryptProtectData(), but that's Windows-specific.

Comment: @grawity i didn't realize you were only interested in Linux. You're on your own there; except to say it is open source - and you *have* heard of `CryptProtectData`.

Comment: @Ian: I'm interested in both.

Answer (score 2):

[LastPass](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lastpass-password-manager/) does the job - in addition to acting as a password manager it gives you the ability to hide the passwords used by the browser. Unless of course you have the master password - depending on how worried you are...remember, once someone has your laptop, all security bets are off!

Comment: I agree with Rory that handing over a laptop is not very wise

Answer (score 0):

[allpword](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nflaalfccepocdgcbcjjecaalcinfneb) helps you manage all your accounts and passwords information securely.
You can backup passwords on gdocs or in browser cache.
 All these passwords stored on gdocs or in browser cache are protected by a single masterkey.
 Without knowledge of the masterkey, no one can access your account and password information.

Master key should help you in case you are more worried that they will check what your saved passwords are rather than them logging into your account from your laptop.